# Angular with Spring Controller

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In my current application when user hits the First URL the control goes to SPRING MVC controller and JSP page name is returned and the JSP is rendered.
We are using angularjs in the Front end.So when the JSP page is getting rendered the ajax call is being made from the Angular controller for bringing the DATA in JSON from SPRING MVC Controller.

So my only question is that there is any other way not to hit the SPRING controller twice.

1. First for returning the JSP page and
2. Second for the ajax call hit to the Spring controller for the JSON data.

P.S - Spring Controller(**@ResponseBody)** is bringing the DATA in JSON automatically and in FE,  AngularJs is taking care of the JSON to load all the fields.

Comment: I think the best approach is to get rid of your jsp and move the view part also to angular.

Comment: I would suggest you to check some basic tutorials with spring and angular. I am concerned about usage of jsp as it kills the purpose of using  angular for front-end.

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't know if you can get only one request to server from FE. But, if you can that will be not so effective and not so scale as two requests. From the FE Angular has all needed structure for gets the pages and data. Keep separate view and data.

Comment: The first URL hit is only for rendering the page, the second one will hit the DATABASE and get all the necessary data in JSON.
Just want to know if in 1 hit can I get the DB call and render the page??